# SwiftUI TextField in a Sheet on macOS Bug

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

The following code shows the bug. If you put a TextField in a .sheet on macOS, when you type some text, move the cursor to the middle, and type or delete, the cursor will move to the end. This only happens in this situation.

Has anyone found a workaround?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false
    @State private var sheetText = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Button("Open Sheet") {
                    isSheetPresented = true
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
                SheetView(sheetText: $sheetText)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var sheetText: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter text", text: $sheetText)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I’ve identified the problem as being that you cannot assign a variable to a sheet that is on the same view. This doesn’t matter if it’s through a secondary view, or directly in the .sheet modifier. As long as the variable that holds the text is in the “parent” view, the behaviour occurs. In the example I submitted this is because I pass it as a binding. In the example below I simply have it on the same view, and as you can see, it resets the cursor (I assume because the view is recalculating). In this instance, SwiftUI should preserve the cursor position.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false
    @State private var sheetText = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Button("Open Sheet") {
                    isSheetPresented = true
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Enter text", text: $sheetText)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never been able to use the out-of-the-box SwiftUI TextField in production on macOS -- it's too buggy. I always have to wrap AppKit components.

Comment: Which do you recommend?

Comment: Which AppKit component? `NSTextView` or `NSTextField` (Likely the latter if it's a relatively simple use case)

Comment: NSTextField, I've looked and while there are ton in GitHub, it does feel like a shame to have to do it.

Comment: Does `.sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) { [sheetText] in` work?

Comment: Nope, it says it's never used and the problem remains. I've reported it to Apple, I'm a bit surprised that it hasn't been reported. I redesigned my views to not reuse the same state variable, but there's no reason this should be necessary.

Comment: Off topic but it doesn't need to be a sheet, I can reproduce this in other situations as well when the field(s) is inside a `Form` or `Group`

Comment: I delete my answer. As I think downvoting a working answer is very impolite. Surely you can disagree my answer, but downvote a working answer is too much. If you downvote a working answer, what for an answer doesn't work? An answer is from someone's kindness, it should never be treated like that.